# php exec how to see progress

Tags: php, exec, return, progress

I have a php script that run 2 exec.

```
exec(".....", $output, $return1);
echo $return1;
exec(".....", $output, $return2);
echo $return2;
```

This 2 exec take 1 minute each to run.
When I run this script, I'm waiting 2 minutes and it result "00".
It's OK but I would like to see `$return1`; after 1 minute and see `$return2` after 1 minute.
I have to use Ajax / js ?
In fact, I would make a progress bar, when first exec is done => 50% when second exec is done => 100%

Thank a lot for your help!

---

Start solution :

Something like this :

define.php :

```
setInterval(function() {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'convert.php?file='+id_file,
    cache:false,
    success:function(result){
        $('.content_box').html(result);

    }
});

}, 3000);
```

Convert.php :

```
exec(convert id_file.pdf id_file.jpg, $output, $return1);
echo $return1;
exec(convert -resize50x50 id_file.jpg id_file_thumb.jpg, $output, $return2);
echo $return2;
```

But it run without callback and non-stop!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you have to use AJAX - just keep your script as is, and you will need another script that reports the progress and/or partial results of the original script. The original script can use $_SESSION to pass the progress / partial results information, that's the simplest solution.

Or, you could use AJAX request not just to report progress/partial results, but to run the action stage by stage, as Zar is probably proposing. But this approach is less flexible; there might be some global data that the stages share, so it is better if they are both within one script run. So the approach I sketched in the 1st paragraph is more viable.

Comment: Thank, ok, I will develop a ajax script with Jquery.
can you advise me?
one php file for one "exec" and 2 scripts jquery or one php file with two "exec" and one script jquery?

Comment: @SebGouaille, go ahead for the solution I sketched in the 1st paragraph, so *'one php file with two "exec"' and one php file for the ajax (it might even all be within one php file).

Answer (score 1):

You could do it in javascript and AJAAX, indeed.
Look into `setTimeout()` and AJAX.

You could specify GET or POST data so the server know what function to run.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any way to control When PHP returns the results. The best option would to exec one of them, then return that. Once the first one has run set it to then run the second one.

Comment: But as it states on PHP.net flushing a buffer it is unreliable.

Answer (score 0):

If the `exec()`'ed apps output progress information, you can even get this: Classically we do this with a redirection trick:

First Create a shell script like

```
#!/bin/bash
$OUTFILE=$1
shift
your_executable "$@" > $OUTFILE &
echo $!
```

then

- Create (closed) temp file
- `exec()` the script with temp filename as first parameter and store the returned PID
- Now poll the temp file, whenever you find new lines `echo` them and `fflush()`
- When the process with the stored pid has exited, exit your script