# Do something while exec is being executed

Tags: php, exec

I write a php script that calls a python script which returns an html table. the PHP script gets the HTML table from the python script and print it to the page.
I use exec to run the python script and I print the return value. 
This process takes a few seconds and I want to print a message to the user (only dots for a start) while he is waiting. This doesn't seem to work because I don't know how to tell the PHP "do something until exec is done".

This is a how I run the python script (I am using '> /dev/null &' so it won't wait for it to finish:

```
exec("c:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe /c c:\\Python27\\python.exe c:\\script.py".' '.$param1.' '.$param2.' '.'> /dev/null &', $return_data, $return_code);
while(!(isset($return_code)))
{
    echo '.';
}
```

I realized that I do that because $return_code is getting set to 0 in the beginning. Is there another way to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can check this out https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.thread.php

I don't know if it works on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve a progress indicator you could use a session variable like *$_SESSION["running"] = true;* and then use AJAX calls to poll the status.

This post shows a possible solution:
[php exec how to see progress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9017258/php-exec-how-to-see-progress)